# Effective query with multiple conditions

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database with

```
books          (primary key: bookID)
characterNames (foreign key: books.bookID) 
locations      (foreign key: books.bookID)
```

The in-text-position of character names and locations are saved in the corresponding tables.
Now I want to write a Python script using psycopg2 to find all occurrences of a given character name and a given location in books, where both occur.
At the moment, I execute 4 queries:

```
SELECT bookID, position FROM characterNames WHERE name='XXX';
--> result is saved in list 'charnames'

SELECT DISTINCT bookID FROM characterNames WHERE name='XXX';
--> result is saved in list 'charnamesIDs'

SELECT bookID, position FROM locations WHERE locName='YYY';
--> result is saved in list 'locs'

SELECT bookID FROM locations WHERE locName='YYY';
--> result is saved in list 'locsIDs'
```

Both queries could give me bookIDs where just the name OR the location appears. So my goal is to eliminate all elements of 'charnames' with bookIDs not occuring in 'locs' and the other way round. My approach was:

```
for cnameTuple in charnames:  
~if cnameTuple[0] in locsIDs:  
~~continue  
~del(cname)
```

I made a corresponding loop for the tuples in locs.
This algorithm unfortunately needs a lot of time. Is there a way to perform this task quicker?

Comment: I rolled back the last edits, as those went into [this separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10273604/939860) now (as advised).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be **much faster and simpler** with a query using JOINs.
Something like this:

```
SELECT b.*, c.position, l.position
FROM   books b
JOIN   characternames c USING (bookid)
JOIN   locations l USING (bookid)
WHERE  c.name = 'XXX'
AND    l.locname = 'YYY';
```

- It is generally a good idea to [only retrieve the data you need from the database server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7510092/939860) instead of fetching excessive data and filtering in your app. Database engines are optimized for filtering and sorting. You can hardly ever match that in your app to begin with.
- Note how I use all lower case names. Read the [manual about identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).
- The manual on the [SELECT statement, in particular about JOINs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

---

#### More info after comment

"Thousands of books" are no problem at all for a RDBMS like PostgreSQL that is designed to handle *millions*. The key to performance with large tables are proper [indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html). For the queries here the following indexes will potentially help:

```
CREATE INDEX books_bookid_idx ON books(bookid); -- a primary key will do, too

CREATE INDEX cn_bookid_idx ON characternames (bookid);
CREATE INDEX cn_name_idx ON characternames (name);

CREATE INDEX locations_bookid_idx ON locations (bookid);
CREATE INDEX locations_locname_idx ON locations (locname);
```

[Multicolumn indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) may perform even better. Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html), it will show you which indexes get used and how fast the query is. Creating indexes is very fast, experimenting with them is easy. Just don't keep indexes you don't need. They carry a maintenance cost, too.

---

#### Optimized query

I `think` I understand now, what you are looking for. This query should be optimized to get all positions of locations or names per `bookid`, but only where name *and* location show up in the same book, and no further details per book:

```
WITH b AS (
    SELECT bookid
    FROM   characternames
    WHERE  name = 'XXX'
    GROUP  BY 1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT bookid
    FROM   locations
    WHERE  l.locname = 'YYY'
    GROUP  BY 1
    )
SELECT bookid, position, 'char' AS what
FROM   b
JOIN   characternames USING (bookid)
WHERE  name = 'XXX'
UNION  ALL
SELECT bookid, position, 'loc' AS what
FROM   b
JOIN   locations USING (bookid)
WHERE  locname = 'YYY'
ORDER  BY bookid, position;
```

#### Major points

- The [CTE (`WITH` query)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) makes sure the base query is only executed once.
- [`INTERSECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-INTERSECT) picks only `bookids` that feature both location *and* name.
- The [`UNION ALL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html) in the final `SELECT` returns *all* found positions. Use `UNION` instead if you want to trim duplicates with the same position.
- I order by `bookid, position` - guessing that is what's needed.
- Added a column `what` to tag the source (location or name) of a position.

---

#### Further optimization

If search terms appear **many times** per book you could considerably speed up the search by creating auxiliary tables with **distinct** entries for `(bookid, term)`. Create a multicolumn primary index on the two columns and an additional one on just `term`. Create one such table for locations and another one for names. Keep them up to date with triggers if need should be, but I assume the content of books is not changing much. Would simplify and speed up the CTE.

If that still isn't fast enough, look into [Full Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html).

Comment: Hello and sorry I hadn't responsed yet.  
Using JOIN was my first approach, but I was told it's to expensive. I'm working on a corpus of thousands of books, so a cross join can take its time. (I may be wrong, but your solution is sort of a cross join with additional conditions. Feel free to correct me, if I'm wrong.)
I'm fine with this, but is there a possibility, to get all positions just once? As a (bookID/c.position/l.position) tuple, I get e.g.
`4/10/20`
`4/10/24`
`4/18/20`
`4/18/24`
I get every (name/locname) pair per bookID, so there's also redundant data.

Comment: @EarlGrey: A cross join would be a join without join condition. There is no cross join here. And while a join has its cost, it is guaranteed to be faster by an order of magnitude than what you had in your question. Now, if you clearly define *which* position per book and which other data with you want, I'll be able to supply the query. The first? Last? From `characterNames` or from `locations`? An array of all positions? Try sample data to show what you want, if you have trouble  expressing it clearly. But edit your question for that. Don't put it in comments.

Comment: I took a guess at what I *think* you might need.

Comment: +1 for outstanding effort in answering. Take all of my upvotes!

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need. Sorry I hadn't made it clear enough. Thank you very much for your help, both on SQL and asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: I really like your solution and want to use it, but the server I'm working on runs PSQL 8.3. CTE was implemented since PSQL 8.4. Without updating PSQL, I have to substitute 'b' every time by myself, right?

Comment: @EarlGrey: You could use a temporary table for `b`. Should be faster. But really, you should look into upgrading. Version 9.1 is so much better than v8.3 - [which is reaching end of life soon](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Updating to 9.1 is no possible option at the moment, therefore I'm using temporary tables and it's fast enough for now.

Comment: I expanded the question for more than 2 conditions. Maybe you can have a look again? I would be happy ^^

Comment: @EarlGrey: I suppose you start a new question for the new question. Link back to this one if the context is useful. It's confusing for the general public to find multiple questions in one post and answers for different stages of the question. BTW, it's CTE for Common Table Expression.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Ok, I asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10273604/1315186).

Answer (score 0):

You can use set to `see` if it speeds up the operation

```
>>> xxx = set([(1,'a'), (2,'b')])
>>> xxx
set([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')])
>>> xxx = set([(1,'a'), (3,'c')])
>>> yyy
set([(1, 'a'), (3, 'c')])
>>> c = xxx.intersection(yyy)
>>> c
set([(1, 'a')])   # common between xxx and yyy
>>> xxx - c
set([(2, 'b')])
```