# Effective query merging more than 2 subqueries

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database with

```
books          (primary key: bookID)
characterNames (foreign key: books.bookID) 
locations      (foreign key: books.bookID)
```

The in-text-position of character names and locations are saved in the corresponding tables.
I'm writing a Pythonscript using psycopg2, finding all occurences of given character names and locations in books. I only want the occurences in books, where both the character name AND the location are found.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10036645/1315186) I already got a solution for searching one location and one character:

```
WITH b AS (  
    SELECT bookid  
    FROM   characternames  
    WHERE  name = 'XXX'  
    GROUP  BY 1  
    INTERSECT  
    SELECT bookid  
    FROM   locations  
    WHERE  l.locname = 'YYY'  
    GROUP  BY 1  
    )  
SELECT bookid, position, 'char' AS what  
FROM   b  
JOIN   characternames USING (bookid)  
WHERE  name = 'XXX'  
UNION  ALL  
SELECT bookid, position, 'loc' AS what  
FROM   b  
JOIN   locations USING (bookid)  
WHERE  locname = 'YYY'  
ORDER  BY bookid, position;
```

The CTE 'b' contains all bookid's, where the character name 'XXX' and the location 'YYY' appear.

Now I'm additionally wondering about searching for 2 places and a name (or 2 names and a place respectively). It's simple if all searched entities must occur in one book, but what about this:
Searching for: Tim, Al, Toolshop
Results: books including
(Tim, Al, Toolshop) or
(Tim, Al) or
(Tim, Toolshop) or
(Al, Toolshop)

The problem could be repeated for 4, 5, 6...conditions.
I thougt about INTERSECTing more subqueries, but that wouldn't work.
Instead I would UNION the found bookIDs, GROUP them and select bookid's occurring more then once:

```
WITH b AS (  
    SELECT bookid, count(bookid) AS occurrences  
    FROM  
        (SELECT DISTINCT bookid  
        FROM characterNames  
        WHERE name='XXX'  
        UNION  
        SELECT DISTINCT bookid  
        FROM characterNames  
        WHERE name='YYY'  
        UNION  
        SELECT DISTINCT bookid  
        FROM locations  
        WHERE locname='ZZZ'  
        GROUP BY bookid)  
    WHERE occurrences>1)
```

I think this works, can't test it at the moment, but is it the best way to do this?

Comment: +1 You put effort into it. Everybody on SO appreciates a clearly formatted and phrased question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea to use a count for the generalized case is sound. A couple of adjustments to the syntax, though:

```
WITH b AS (  
   SELECT bookid
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT bookid  
      FROM   characterNames  
      WHERE  name='XXX'  

      UNION ALL  
      SELECT DISTINCT bookid  
      FROM   characterNames  
      WHERE  name='YYY'  

      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT bookid  
      FROM   locations  
      WHERE  locname='ZZZ'  
      ) x
   GROUP  BY bookid
   HAVING count(*) > 1
   )
SELECT bookid, position, 'char' AS what
FROM   b
JOIN   characternames USING (bookid)
WHERE  name = 'XXX'

UNION  ALL
SELECT bookid, position, 'loc' AS what
FROM   b
JOIN   locations USING (bookid)
WHERE  locname = 'YYY'
ORDER  BY bookid, position;
```

#### Notes

- Use `UNION ALL` (not `UNION`) to preserve duplicates between the subqueries. You want them in this case to be able to count them.
- The subqueries are supposed to produces distinct values. It works with `DISTINCT` the way you have it. You may want to try `GROUP BY 1` instead and see if that performs better (I don't expect it to.)
- The `GROUP BY` hast to go outside the subquery. It would only be applied to the last subquery and makes no sense there as you have `DISTINCT bookid` already.
- The check whether there are more than one hits on a book has to go into a `HAVING` clause:

  ```
   HAVING count(*) > 1
  ```

  You can not use aggregated values in a `WHERE` clause.

---

#### Combining conditions on one table

You cannot *simply* combine multiple conditions on one table. How will you count the number of findings? But there is a somewhat more sophisticated way. May or may not improve  performance, You'll have to test (with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html)). Both queries require at least two index scans for the table `characterNames`. At least it shortens the syntax.

Consider how I compute the number of hits for `characterNames` and how I changed to `sum(hits)` in the outer `SELECT`:

```
WITH b AS (  
   SELECT bookid
   FROM  (
      SELECT bookid
           , max((name='XXX')::int)
           + max((name='YYY')::int) AS hits
      FROM   characterNames  
      WHERE  (name='XXX'
           OR name='YYY')
      GROUP  BY bookid

      UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT bookid, 1 AS hits  
      FROM   locations  
      WHERE  locname='ZZZ'  
      ) x
   GROUP  BY bookid
   HAVING sum(hits) > 1
   )
...
```

Converting a `boolean` to `integer` gives `0` for `FALSE` and `1` for `TRUE`. That helps.

---

#### Faster with EXISTS

While riding my bike to my company this thing kept kicking at the back of my head. I have reason to believe this query might be even faster. Please give it a try:

```
WITH b AS (  
   SELECT bookid

        , (EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   characterNames c
            WHERE  c.bookid = b.bookid
            AND    c.name = 'XXX'))::int
        + (EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   characterNames c
            WHERE  c.bookid = b.bookid
            AND    c.name = 'YYY'))::int AS c_hits

        , (EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   locations l
            WHERE  l.bookid = b.bookid
            AND    l.locname='ZZZ'))::int AS l_hits
   FROM   books b  
   WHERE  (c_hits + l_hits) > 1
   )
SELECT c.bookid, c.position, 'char' AS what
FROM   b
JOIN   characternames c USING (bookid)
WHERE  b.c_hits > 0
AND    c.name IN ('XXX', 'YYY')

UNION  ALL
SELECT l.bookid, l.position, 'loc' AS what
FROM   b
JOIN   locations l USING (bookid)
WHERE  b.l_hits > 0
AND    l.locname = 'YYY'
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

- The `EXISTS` semi-join can stop executing at the first match. As we are only interested in an all-or-nothing answer in the CTE, this could possibly do the job *much* faster.
- This way we also don't need to aggregate (no `GROUP BY` necessary).
- I also remember whether *any* characters or locations were found and only revisit tables with actual matches.

Comment: Ah, yes...the HAVING statement, I remeber (= Does the HAVING statement need 'count(*) AS occurences' at the beginning? Again, I only need the IDs

Comment: @EarlGrey: If you only need the IDs, the CTE is also not needed. I trimmed the unneeded parts of the query.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I only need the IDs in the CTE. My script still needs the IDs and the positions of the occurences, but not 'occurences'

Comment: @EarlGrey: Ah, I see. Rolled back my last edit and adjusted accordingly.

Comment: +1 Ok, thank you very much. My skill in writing (postgre)SQL queries benefited a lot.

Comment: Ok, I see I can't simply edit the answer ^^ I wanted to suggest using `WHERE name='XXX' OR name='YYY'` instead of go through the table twice.

Comment: @EarlGrey: You should be able to propose an edit. But I picked up your idea and added a bit to my answer.

Comment: @EarlGrey: I came up with yet another idea. Can you test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and report your findings?

Comment: Well, at the moment I run INSERT queries on temporary tables, due I can't use CTE with the psql version on the server. I can `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` corresponding INSERT queries, if that's also ok. Otherwise I think I could get the admin to update until...2 weeks or so.

Comment: @EarlGrey: Never mind. Just let us know if you find out. Fixed a bug in the third query, btw.