# More efficient way to do a SQL query?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Is there a better way to do the following calculation of `sales - returns = total`?

```
exchange_rates = self.rates_dict

self.DBConnection.cursor.execute("SELECT royalty_price, royalty_currency FROM sales_raw WHERE provider='%s' AND sales_or_return = 'S' AND date='%s'"%(provider, self.date))
data = list(self.DBConnection.cursor.fetchall())
sales_in_usd = sum(float(price) * exchange_rates[currency] for price, currency in data)

self.DBConnection.cursor.execute("SELECT royalty_price, royalty_currency FROM sales_raw WHERE provider='%s' AND sales_or_return = 'R' AND date='%s'"%(provider, self.date))
data = list(self.DBConnection.cursor.fetchall())
returns_in_usd = sum(float(price) * exchange_rates[currency] for price, currency in data)

total_in_usd = sales_in_usd - returns_in_usd
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(royalty_price), SUM(royalty_currency) FROM sales_raw WHERE....

Comment: Why.... WHY do you use the `%` operator? NEVER use it for SQL queries. It enables SQL injection. use `WHERE field = %s` without quotes and pass the list of params as a second argument to the `execute` function!

Comment: I think this is very similar to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507577/matrix-multiplication-in-python-and-mysql The only apparent difference is you want to subtract the results of two subselects. And, yes, you can do this in SQL.

Comment: Every dbapi implementation needs to support params. `%s` might be wrong but using the `%` *operator* is *always* wrong.

Comment: Having said all of that, @ThiefMaster, OP is doing it wrong, so good catch :) I deleted my comment string since I ultimately see what you were saying and I just blabbered on basically supporting your argument. My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT    
    royalty_currency,
    SUM (
          CASE sales_or_return 
          when 'R' then royalty_price * -1
          else royalty_price
       ) as TotalSales
  WHERE provider=%s AND date = %s AND sales_or_return IN ('S', 'R')
    GROUP BY royalty_currency
```

I'm not 100% sure this will compile on MySQL try it first. If it does ... great ... if not, let me know since I have another idea. Once you get this, multiply by the exchange rate for that given currency.

EDIT: added `AND sales_or_return IN ('S', 'R')` per @ypercube's recommendation. Additionally, this assumes that all currency is the same. You will still need to iterate the results according to their exchange rates. If the exchange rates are stored in a database then you could join the data on the exchange rate table. Not being a great accountant, I don't know if you'd want to capture the exchange rate at time of sale or if everything is calculated as of current exchange rates. My assumption is that, at this point, you're calculating sales against current exchange rates that you're obtaining via a web service.

An alternative query could be:

```
SELECT sales.royalty_currency, sales.GrossSales, returns.GrossReturns, sales.GrossSales - returns.GrossReturns, 
(SELECT sum(royalty_price) GrossSales, royalty_currency 
    FROM sales_raw 
    WHERE provider=%s AND sales_or_return = 'S' AND date=%s) sales
JOIN 
(SELECT sum(royalty_price) GrossReturns, royalty_currency 
    FROM sales_raw 
    WHERE provider=%s AND sales_or_return = 'R' AND date=%s) returns
on sales.royalty_currency = returns.royalty_currency
```

This one could probably be refined a bit more, also. It also gets you some other information that might be useful for other reporting purposes.

Comment: You also need `AND sales_or_return IN ('S', 'R')` in the Where clause.

Comment: The `%s` references shouldn't be quoted -- they should be used unquoted, and the database driver itself (not Python's string formatting operators!) should be used to substitute actual values. (Some other DB-API drivers require `?` in place of `%s` -- check the docs, or use a layer such as SQLAlchemy's query builder which abstracts these details away). Doing this the wrong way can result in SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed. MySQLdb and psycopg2 both accept `%s`. I'm personally more comfortable with the `?` but have grown accustomed to tossing in `%s` as long as it's formatted properly within the context of a db connection.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, let the database do the work (by using `sum` directly in your sql statement).

EDIT: You can `group by` currency type to have one `total` per currency type.

Comment: Might be more difficult than just using SUM if he doesn't have the exchange rates in the database.

Comment: Could group them by currency, so at least there would be less work to do after the query.

Comment: Math says that all he has to do is get the base difference of the sum and then multiply by the rates.

Comment: @Mark Byers: true remark, but at this point the question is a little underspecified I guess. You could use a simple `group by` to combine values of the same currency then.

Comment: I just realized that perhaps each sale could be at a different exchange rate. That complicates things.

Comment: @swasheck: that would be a definite case for getting those exchange rates in the database too...

Comment: @ChristopheD exchange rates are dynamic. it depends on GAAP, with which I am certainly not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Not the least lines of code, but intuitive and readable, can be condensed to skip steps if needed

1. Put the exchange rates in your database.  Lets assume its in the database with columns royalty_currency and exrate
2. Join the exchange rates table with the sales_raw table

   (SELECT sales_raw.provider, sales_raw.royalty_price, sales_raw.royalty_currency, sales_raw.sales_or_return, exchange_rates.exrate 
   FROM sales_raw 
   INNER JOIN exchange_rates 
   ON sales_raw.royalty_currency = exchange_rates.royalty_currency) sales
3. Pivot up by sales and returns

   (SELECT provider, royalty_currency, exrate
   CASE sales_or_return WHEN 'S' THEN royalty_price ELSE 0 AS royalty_sales
   CASE sales_or_return WHEN 'R' THEN royalty_price ELSE 0 AS royalty_returns
   FROM sales) pivoted_sales
4. Calculate the total

   SELECT SUM(royalty_sales * exrate) - SUM(royalty_returns * exrate) AS total_sum FROM pivoted_sales