# how to make join table update efficient in sql (it's efficient from my ruby code!!)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

This is something weird I can't really understand, I'm working in PostGreSql9.2 ...

I have this database:

```
movies (id, title, votes)
infos (id, movie_id, info_type, value)
```

I want to update movies.votes with infos.value, joining on movies.id = infos.movie_if and only where info_type = 100 (which is the type for votes..)

I tried 2 different queries:

```
update movies
set votes = cast(i.value as integer)
from movies m inner join infos i on m.id = i.movie_id
where i.info_type = 100
```

which (using explain) predicts a running time of about 11 million seconds (too much!)

second try:

```
update movies m
set votes = cast(
(
  select value
  from infos i
  where i.info_type = 100 and i.movie_id = m.id
  limit 1
) AS integer);
```

this one whould be "only" 20 thousands seconds.. still far too much

I don't really know how the query plan work, so I tries to do this with a ruby script (using active_record)... which is:

```
Info.find_in_batches(:conditions => "info_type = 100") do |group|
    group.each{ |info|
        movie = Movie.find(info.movie_id)
        movie.votes = info.value.to_i
        movie.save
    }
end
```

For those of you who don't read ruby, this query simply loops thru all infos that meet the info_type = 100 condition, then for each one it searches the corresponding movie and updates it..

And it was very fast! just a few minutes, and with all the ruby/orm overhead!!

Now, why?? Know that movies is about 600k records, but only 200k (a third) have an info record with the number of votes. Still this doesn't explain what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `EXPLAIN`

As [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) already explained, you probably misunderstood what `EXPLAIN` is telling you. If you want actual times in seconds, use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Be aware though, that this actually executes the statement. I quote the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html):

> Important: Keep in mind that the statement is actually executed when
> the `ANALYZE` option is used. Although `EXPLAIN` will discard any
> output that a `SELECT` would return, other side effects of the
> statement will happen as usual. If you wish to use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`
> on an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `CREATE` `TABLE AS`, or `EXECUTE`
> statement without letting the command affect your data, use this
> approach:
>
> ```
> BEGIN;
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...;
> ROLLBACK;
> ```

Still, the estimates for the first query are way to high and indicate a grave problem.

#### What's wrong?

As to your **third approach**: for big tables, it will **always** be faster by an order of magnitude to have the database server update a whole (big) table at once than sending instructions to the server for every row - even more so if the new values come from within the database. More in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518619/939860). If your tests show otherwise, chances are that something is wrong with your (test) setup. And in fact, it is ...

Your **first query** goes *wrong completely*. The god-awful performance estimate is indication of how terribly wrong it is. While you join the table `movies` to the table `infos` in the `FROM` clause, you forget the `WHERE` condition to bind the resulting rows to the rows in the `UPDATE` table. This leads to a `CROSS JOIN`, i. e. **every** row in `movies` (600k) is updated with **every** single vote in `values` (200k) resulting in **120 000 000 000 updates**. Yummy. And all wrong. Never execute this. Not even in a transaction that can be rolled back.

Your **second query** goes *wrong, too*. It runs a *correlated subquery*, i. e. it runs a separate query for every row. That's 600k subqueries instead of just 1, hence terrible performance.

That's right: 600k subqueries. Not 200k. You instruct Postgres to update **every** movie, no matter what. Those without a matching `infos.value` (no `info_type = 100`), receive a `NULL` value  in `votes`, overwriting whatever was there before.

Also, I wonder what that `LIMIT 1` is doing there?

- Either `(infos.movie_id, infos.info_type)` is `UNIQUE`, then you don't need `LIMIT`.
- Or it isn't `UNIQUE`. Then add a `UNIQUE index` to `infos` if you intend to keep the structure.

#### Proper query

```sql
UPDATE movies m
SET    votes = i.value::int
FROM   infos i
WHERE  m.id = i.movie_id
AND    i.info_type = 100
AND    m.votes IS DISTINCT FROM i.value::int;
```

This is much like your first query, just simplified and doing it right. Plus:

- No need to join to `movies` a second time. You only need `infos` in the `FROM` clause.
- Actually bind the row to be updated to the row carrying the new value, thereby avoiding the (unintended) `CROSS JOIN`:

  ```
    WHERE  m.id = i.movie_id
  ```
- Avoid empty updates, they carry a cost for no gain. That's what the last line is for.

Should be a matter of seconds or less, not millions of seconds.

BTW, *indexes* will not help this query, table scans are faster for the described data distribution since you use all (or a third) of the rows in involved tables.

Comment: thank you for the good answer, the LIMIT 1 was useless I know.. but now I understand why it was so slow, thanks! I've tries and it works well

Answer (score 1):

> […] which (using explain) predicts a running time of about 11 million seconds (too much!)
>
> […] this one whould be "only" 20 thousands seconds.. still far too much

I think you are misunderstanding the output of `EXPLAIN`. As explained in [its documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-explain.html), the "estimated statement execution cost" (i.e. "the planner's guess at how long it will take to run the statement") is not measured in *seconds*, but "in cost units that are arbitrary, but conventionally mean disk page fetches".

So PostgreSQL is guessing that the second statement will run about 500 times faster than the first statement, but neither one will take anywhere near as long you think. :-)