# PostgreSQL get serial value from primary key to foreign key

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, concurrency

I'm writing a python script that accesses my postgres database. In addition, I'm importing a .csv file to take the data and transfer it to the postgres database.

I have something like this and I apologize if I can't seem to format correctly as I'm new here.

Table foo:

```
A SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
B
C
```

Table bar:

```
D INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
E
F INT REFERENCES foo(A)
```

My code looks something like this:

```
csvfile = open('something.csv')
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=something user=something password=something")
cur = conn.cursor()
datareader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in datareader:

cur.execute("INSERT INTO bar (D, E, F) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (row['some_int'], row['some_char']), [not_sure_what_goes_here])
```

I do not know how to pull the serial value from table `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basic solution

*Basically* (but keep reading!), you want to `INSERT` a row into `foo` first and use the automatically generated `A` for the next `INSERT` into `bar`.
You *could* do that with two round trips to the DB, but that would be unreasonably *expensive* and much more susceptible to *concurrency* issues. You want to get this done in a [*single* trip to the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518619/939860).

In Postgres 9.1+ you can use a **data-modifying CTE** to execute two inserts in one statement:

```
cur.execute("""WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO foo (B, C)
   VALUES (%s, %s)
   RETURNING A
   )
INSERT INTO bar (D, E, F)
SELECT %s, %s, A
FROM ins""", (val_for_b, val_for_c, val_for_d, val_for_e)
```

**However**, the above code implies that you can insert `(B, C)` into `foo` unconditionally. That's rarely the case. Typically you have some kind of unique constraint on `foo` and want to insert `(B, C)` only if it's not there, yet. You have a "**SELECT-or-INSERT**" problem, which is further complicated by **possible race conditions** with concurrent write operations (if possible). The best solution depends on your exact requirements.

### Mostly-safe solution

To solve the "SELECT-or-INSERT" problem and also *minimize* chances for a race condition:

```
cur.execute("""WITH param(_B, _C) AS (SELECT %s::text, %s::text)
, sel AS (SELECT A FROM foo, param WHERE B = _B AND C = _C FOR SHARE)
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO foo (B, C)
   SELECT _B, _C FROM param
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sel)
   RETURNING A
   )
INSERT INTO bar (D, E, F)
SELECT %s, %s, COALESCE(sel.A, ins.A)
FROM   sel FULL JOIN ins""", (val_for_b, val_for_c, val_for_d, val_for_e)
```

Replace the type cast `::text` with your actual data types (that you did not provide).
This should be good enough for most use cases. It still leaves a *tiny* chance for a race condition, when  two transaction try to insert the same row in `foo` concurrently.

### Safe solution

To be perfectly sure, consider a server-side function like discussed in this related answer. You'll find detailed explanation for the above SQL code as well:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Then your call can be:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO bar (D, E, F)
VALUES(%s, %s, f_foo_id(%s, %s))""", (val_for_d, val_for_e, val_for_b, val_for_c)
```