# Grouping but with keeping all non-NULL values

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the table:

```
 ID |  Name | Intolerance
  1 |   Amy |     Lactose
  2 | Brian |     Lactose
  3 |   Amy |      Gluten
```

And I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    CASE 
       WHEN Intolerance = 'Lactose' 1
    END AS Lactose,
    CASE 
       WHEN Intolerance = 'Gluten' 1
    END AS Gluten
FROM 
    Table
```

I get:

```
  Name   | Lactose | Gluten
  -------+---------+--------
  Amy    |    1    |
  Amy    |         |   1
  Brian  |    1    |
```

But if I try to add "GROUP BY Name", Amy won't have a 1 in both columns, because GROUP BY only selects the last row of each Name. What I want to get instead is this:

```
 Name | Lactose | Gluten
------+---------+---------
  Amy |       1 |      1
Brian |       1 |
```

How can I get that? Is there perhaps a more efficient way to summarize who's allergic to what from the same input? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could take the MAX of each column within each group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) then the aggregate functions can be used for columns that aren't in the GROUP BY.

In this case I assume you want to use [MAX](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp), to get only a 1 or a NULL.

[SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) or COUNT can also be used to surround a `CASE WHEN`.
But then those would return a total.

```
SELECT 
 Name,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Intolerance = 'Lactose' THEN 1 END) AS Lactose,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Intolerance = 'Gluten' THEN 1 END) AS Gluten
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Or if you don't want to see NULL's?
Then let the CASE return a varchar instead of a number.

```
SELECT 
 Name,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Intolerance = 'Lactose' THEN '1' ELSE '' END) AS Lactose,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Intolerance = 'Gluten' THEN '1' ELSE '' END) AS Gluten
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the sum of the number of number of intolerances for each person. Also, put a `ELSE` so the value is `0` or `1`:

```
SELECT 
     Name,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Intolerance = 'Lactose' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Lactose,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Intolerance = 'Gluten' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gluten
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that each time I encounter a question like that, it's because a no proper amount of thinking on design was allowed to the project.

To put it simply : you are trying to move data to columns. This is what your application layer is for ! Not the database. People tend to mix what databases are for with what application / UI layer and vice versa are for !

And each time it happens, I see people reaping their mind to answer because that's the point here : answer the question no matter what. Don't question what the OP want to do, give him the answer...

Sorry for that, I am just a little bit pissed.

**My solution** : 
Keep your original query and do the aesthetic on your UI / application layer side. You probably have a IList inside each Person. Just fill them and give the UI the opportunity to display them however it wants.
Because that's what you're asking the database to do : aesthetics.

Comment: Actually I'm still pretty new to the whole thing and I just couldn't figure out what to search for. It's more for learning and personal use rather than efficiency. I do still appreciate your answer, however. ;)

Comment: @Engreyight Don't worry to much about this yet. Because this is ultimately a design choice. Does one want to put more work on the back-end and send less data to the front-end? Or should the front-end do all the heavy lifting? Such choice is sometimes decided case by case.  Plus, aggregating is something databases are already good at.

Comment: @LukStorms Yes, he might as well render some html with his database. Oh wait, wouldn't it be nice if we could insert some css too based on the intolerance ? He's new to the playground and you're telling him it's ok to eat the sand...

Comment: @olleo Well, in his case doing this pivoting on the front-end would be fine I think.  The extra amount of data send over the network won't be that excessive. But I do think that a doctrine of "Presentation must always be done in the presentation layer" is too strict.  There are nuances, f.e. in [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510092/).  Besides, SQL is also a form of presentation, but at a lower level.

Comment: @LukStorms First, your link is talking about calculation vs presentation. No nuances there. It's clearly separated. The rule is simple : don't do in your app what the database is trained for years to do (and vice versa). This is the basic of S.E. : separation of concerns. Second, you have a premature optimization thinking ("data send...") : that is like having cancer in S.E.